# How to get useEffect to only update on changes when the change is from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, zustand

I am using zustand for state management and am trying to update a component in real time only without refreshing the page when there are changes in the state of the component after retrieving the data once.

Here is my store

```
export const useStore = create((set) => ({
  reservations: [],
  getReservations: async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(baseUrl);
    set({ reservations: response.data });
  },
  setRev: (reservations) => {
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      reservations,
    }));
  },
  addReservation: (reservation) => {
    set((state) => ({ reservations: [...state.reservations, reservation] }));
  },
  removeReservation: (id) => {
    set((state) => ({
      reservations: state.reservations.filter(
        (reservation) => id !== reservation._id
      ),
    }));
  },
}));
```

I have tried using the useEffect hook to retrieve the data as shown in the code below, I have another component which calls the `addReservation` function. The code below results in calling useEffect infinitely instead of updating only when there are changes to `const reservations`, when another component calls the `addReservation` function.

```
const getAllReservation = useStore((state) => state.getReservations);
  const reservations = useStore((state) => state.reservations);
  const reservationsRef = useRef(useStore.getState().reservations);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllReservation()
    useStore.subscribe(
      (reservations) => (reservationsRef.current = reservations),
      (state) => state.reservations
    );
  }, [reservations]);
```

I have tried splitting the useEffects as such but the page needs to be refreshed again to show the updated data. (desired outcome is without refreshing)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getAllReservation()
  }, [])
  useEffect(() => {
    useStore.subscribe(
      (reservations) => (reservationsRef.current = reservations),
      (state) => state.reservations
    );
  }, [reservations]);
```

I have tried putting `[]` as the dependency array as the second argument in the useEffect hook but it does not work as well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try to make another `useEffect` (so you will have 2) just for `getAllReservation()` function.

Comment: i have tried it, but it does not work, thanks

Answer (score 1):

React can't detect changes inside of Ref. So need to pass updated reservations as props or save in local state.

[Zustand docs](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#transient-updates-for-often-occuring-state-changes)

> The subscribe function allows components to bind to a state-portion
> **without forcing re-render on changes**. Best combine it with useEffect
> for automatic unsubscribe on unmount. This can make a drastic
> performance impact when you are allowed to mutate the view directly.

```
  const useStore = create(set => ({ scratches: 0, ... }))
    function Component() {
      // Fetch initial state
      const scratchRef = useRef(useStore.getState().scratches)
      // Connect to the store on mount, disconnect on unmount, catch state-changes in a reference
      useEffect(() => useStore.subscribe(
        scratches => (scratchRef.current = scratches),
        state => state.scratches
      ), [])
```

Comment: I have tried this, it does not work, I have to refresh the page in order to show the updated changes.

Comment: Possibly React can't detect changes inside a Ref, so reservations should be passed as props or saved in local state.

Comment: Hi, using refs was the suggestion i found when reading the user guide from https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand under the Transient Updates section

Comment: """The subscribe function allows components to bind to a state-portion without forcing re-render on changes.""" So it's not updated with ref.